# Flash media server delayed streaming

Tags: red5, fms3

I have a RED5 server I'm using to pass a live streaming between users' cameras.

What I need now is a way to create a delayed broadcast of the camera (intended delay) so that "super users" will be able to see it immediately and others will get it 10-15 seconds later.

If FMS is better for that, I will be happy to know why and how too.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way of doing this and posted it here:
http://rialog.blogspot.com/2010/04/delayed-stream-using-fms-for-semi-live.html

Plaese note that the code in this post is pseudo code only..

Answer (score 0):

Decrease the bit rate of output video depends upon the speed of the connections.